# Is it possible to fetch data using a server function in client side NextJS 14 runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

I am wondering about the various data fetching mechanism given by the NextJS. In my application I have a server side function called `fetchAHistory()` and it is fetching history document data from the MongoDB database.

```
"use server";
import History from "@/models/History";
import { connectToDB } from "@/util/database/database";

export const fetchAHistory = async (cid: string) => {
  console.log(cid);

  try {
    const results = await History.find({ id: cid }, { msgs: 1 });
    console.log(results[0].msgs);

    return results[0].msgs;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

From the documents I referred about server-side data fetching my understand about this kind of server function was, these functions only able to call in `server side`. And render the fetch data as a server component to the client I need to pass the server component as a children to client component. However, in my scenario I was able to call and execute `fetchAHistory()` in `use client` client-side environment and fetch history data successfully without any issues. And `fetchAHistory()` was executed on the server side I was able to verify it by `console.log(results[0].msgs)` seeing the fetching results in the vs code terminal.

```
"use client";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import React, { ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useChat } from "ai/react";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { Avatar } from "../ui/avatar";
import { AvatarFallback, AvatarImage } from "@radix-ui/react-avatar";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { fetchAHistory } from "@/lib/data";

const Chat = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const cid = searchParams.get("cid");

  const [id, setID] = useState(uuidv4);
  const image = "";

  const {
    messages,
    input,
    handleInputChange,
    handleSubmit,
    stop,
    isLoading,
    setMessages,
  } = useChat({
    body: {
      id,
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (cid) {
        const results = await fetchAHistory(cid);
        setMessages(results);
      } else if (!cid) {
        setMessages([]);
      }
    })();
  }, [cid]);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col h-full">
      <div className="overflow-y-auto">
        <div>
          {messages.map((m) => (
            <div
              className={clsx("p-8 flex justify-start", {
                "bg-gray-200 text-gray-800": m.role === "user",
                "bg-gray-100 text-gray-800": m.role !== "user",
              })}
              key={m.id}
            >
              <div className="max-w-[1024px] flex gap-4">
                <Avatar>
                  <AvatarImage
                    src={
                      m.role === "user"
                        ? image
                        : "https://github.com/shadcn.png"
                    }
                    alt="user"
                  />
                  <AvatarFallback>IA</AvatarFallback>
                </Avatar>
                <div className="mt-2">
                  {isLoading && m.role !== "user" ? "Loading" : m.content}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="mt-auto flex">
        {/* <ChatInput /> */}
        <form className="w-full flex gap-2 m-4" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            className="rounded border w-full border-gray-300 p-2 shadow-xl"
            value={input}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
          <Button onClick={stop}>Stop</Button>
          <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Chat;
```

Even though I have seen calling server functions in server side I didn't know I can execute server functions this way in client side.

1. First I like to know, is this is a recommended data fetching method in
   NextJS?
2. And what's are the advantage and disadvantages using server functions to fetch data compared to using API routes provided by NextJS?
3. (Additional) What's the real difference between `'use server'` and `import 'server-only'`.

(updated)
I also came across this [https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#keeping-server-only-code-out-of-the-client-environment][1] next JS documentation about keeping server only code out of client side. But since the `fetchAHistory()` function doesn't use any private keys and all the database operations still execute in server side is there a security risk still there when execution fetchAHistory() in client sid

Comment: Server actions do run in the server but they're technically just an API route that is still called by the client. In your case, the database find is run in the server but the client is initiating a request for that data instead of getting it prerendered. When it comes to fetching data, the best would be to compute it from a server component and pass it to a client component as props, this way the client never initiates a request for it. Fetching server actions are still valid depending on the UX you're trying to achieve, but generally the first option is almost always the best one.